# Dependency injection using EJB annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

Simple WebSevice

```
@WebService
@Stateless
public class HistoryFormatterWebService implements IHistoryFormatterWebService
{
   @EJB
   private IHistoryFormatter historyFormatter;

   public byte[] formatHistory(final byte[] data)
   {
      System.err.println("hello from service");

      return null;
   }
}
```

IHistoryFormatter

```
@Local
public interface IHistoryFormatter
{  
// ..  
}
```

IHistoryFormatter is bean from another project (query-ear.ear) but he is also deployed on jBoss.
My WebService deploy on jBoss normally. And jBoss wrote

```
11:17:09,506 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction] installing MBean: jboss.j2ee:ear=wsformatter-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=wsformatter-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=HistoryFormatterWebService,service=EJB3 with dependencies:
11:17:09,568 INFO  [JmxKernelAbstraction]   jboss.j2ee:ear=query-ear.ear,jar=query-services.jar,name=HistoryFormatter,service=EJB3
11:17:09,568 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.wsformatter.HistoryFormatterWebService ejbName: HistoryFormatterWebService
```

But when I sent request to it (using SoapUI) I get exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Non matching type for inject of field: private com.softcomputer.softlab.lquery.service.IHistoryFormatter com.softcomputer.wsformatter.HistoryFormatterWebService.historyFormatter for type: $Proxy250 of jndiName env/com.softcomputer.wsformatter.HistoryFormatterWebService/historyFormatter
intfs: , com.softcomputer.softlab.lquery.service.IHistoryFormatter, org.jboss.ejb3.JBossProxy
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiFieldInjector.inject(JndiFieldInjector.java:128)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiFieldInjector.inject(JndiFieldInjector.java:106)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiFieldInjector.inject(JndiFieldInjector.java:63)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AbstractPool.create(AbstractPool.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.InfinitePool.get(InfinitePool.java:49)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ThreadlocalPool.create(ThreadlocalPool.java:50)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ThreadlocalPool.get(ThreadlocalPool.java:90)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss42.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:103)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:221)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:466)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:656)
    at org.jboss.injection.JndiFieldInjector.inject(JndiFieldInjector.java:116)
    ... 41 more
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wild guess:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Non matching type for inject of field: 
[...] com.softcomputer.softlab.lquery.service.IHistoryFormatter [...] for type: 
[...] of [...] com.softcomputer.softlab.lquery.service.IHistoryFormatter[...]
```

This sounds to me, that there are *two* classes `IHistoryFormatter` loaded by two classloaders. Even if the classes have the same name they are considered different if they have been loaded by different classloaders.

So check your packaging of the interface classes - ideally they should be available in exactly one place in JBoss.

Comment: It's true. I had lquery.jar and lquery-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in class path